# RxJs: Share an Observable using async / await

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Using RxJs 5 and Angular 4.

I want to share an observable so that I only make 1 Http request, and I also want to await the calls so that I get the result when I request it. I have the following code:

```
export class DataService {
    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
        this.getObservable();  
    }

    public observable;

    public getObservable() {
        const url = "api/getData";
        this.observable = this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}${url}`).share()
    }

    public async hasData(data: DataEnum) {        
        const result = await this.observable.toPromise();
        return result.filter(x => x === data).length > 0;
    }
}
```

However many calls to hasData is resulting in many calls to our api end point. I am assuming that I have set `observable` to a shared observable, and when I call `.toPromise()` it will just get the cached value and make it a promise, which I can `await`.

Is this how it should work?

Comment: why do you want to do that? we can help you with better technique?

Comment: If you're already using promises, is there something that prevents you from saving a promise instead? It will be very straightforward. share operator doesn't work here as you expect.

Comment: @Microsmsm The code is simplified : ) when the app loads I need to know where to direct the user - hence the need to await the result. The data also contains some other information that is requested in the HTML template, so we get lots of calls, that I want to share.

Comment: @estus Feel free to post an answer, that sounds promising!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems overly complex to me.  I would likely do something like:

```
private data = null;

getData():Observable<> {
  // if data is already available, return it immediately
  if (this.data) return Observable.of(this.data);

  // else, fetch from the server and cache result
  return this.http.get(url).do(data => this.data=data)
}
```

So whenever you want the data you just do:

```
this.getData().subscribe(
  data => console.log(data);
)
```

To be sure that you won't call your API endpoints multiple times before the data arrives, you have a few options.

- Look into [data resolvers](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-guard) -- these will not init your component until the data has arrived. In `ngOnInit` the data will be ready synchronously so no risk of calling the server multiple times.
- Alternatively, you can hide the view until the data is ready with `*ngIf="data"` so a user won't click a button multiple times.

Comment: The problem with this is that `data` is set asynchronously, so that if I call `getData()` twice in quick succession and the api call takes some time, it will be called twice.

Comment: @user917170 I added a bit to my answer.

Comment: Ok I think that data resolvers is actually the correct solution to the problem, which wasn't necessarily clear in my question, but yes we want to block loading of a route until the service call returns. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Due to how `share` works, `observable` is resubscribed on `toPromise`, ths produces new requests.

Promises already provide caching behaviour. Considering that promises are already using in service API, they can be used exclusively:

```
constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    this.getPromise();  
}

public promise;

public getPromise() {
    const url = "api/getData";
    this.promise = this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}${url}`).toPromise()
}

public async hasData(data: DataEnum) {        
    const result = await this.promise;
    return result.filter(x => x === data).length > 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this would have worked, but actually route guard data resolvers is the 'angular' way to fix it.